# How to get a SQL trigger to increment by 1 on an update?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a trigger that updates one column on a specific row when it is updated but I am getting this error

> ORA-04091: table table_name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

when I go to test the trigger.

This is my trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tblTrigger
AFTER UPDATE 
ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE employees 
    SET revisions = revisions + 1 
    WHERE ID = ID;
END;
/
```

It is suppose to only update that certain Employees ID revisions

Comment: Look at BEFORE UPDATE and just use something like `:NEW.revisions := :OLD.revisions + 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `BEGIN`...`END` like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblTrigger AFTER INSERT ON employees

FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE employees SET revisions = revisions + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working with yours and Brians answers.

Comment: @ski If your issue is solved then please accept the most relevant answer.